# Very different scale parameter estimates in Poisson regression

Tags: poisson-distribution, goodness-of-fit, overdispersion

**The background**: I'm analysing survival data using a Poisson model. I've splitted the data on 2 time-scales (attained age and calendar year). Attained age is modelled using flexible parametric functions, calendar year is a categorical variable and I've also included the interaction terms between attained age and calendar year.

**The problem**: looking at the goodness-of-fit criteria, I see that the deviance divided by the degrees of freedom (*df*) is 0.03, while the Pearson's  $\chi^2$ divided by the *df* is 5.84. The fact that the former is <1 and the latter is >1 implies that the standard errors associated to my parameter estimates are deflated, if I estimate the scale parameter using *Pearson's  $\chi^2$ / df*, or inflated, if I estimate the scale parameter using *Deviance / df*. This obviously leads to completely different results.

What could be wrong here?

**Edit (04 Jul 2012)**: I think this question can be reformulated also as: with clustered data (i.e. dependent data within each cluster), are the goodness-of-fit criteria for overdispersion (namely Pearson's  $\chi^2$ divided by the residual degrees of freedom and Deviance divided by the residual degrees of freedom) still interpretable? (With iid data, >1 indicates *overdispersion*, while <1 indicates *underdispersion*).

**Edit (19 Aug 2013)**: After delving into this topic a little bit more, I no longer think that in this particular scenario the use of those goodness-of-fit criteria makes sense. In fact, we're only exploiting the GLM framework to fit a survival model characterized by a non-constant baseline incidence rate (see also: piecewise exponential model). We're not assuming that the outcome has a Poisson distribution. For this reason, the question as reformulated in my last edit (04 Jul 2012) is also wrong, as we don't have clustered data here. See this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/22951/9253) for more information.

Comment: A couple questions, not directly related to your question, but which may be helpful: 
I am not sure what you mean by "splitted the data". 

Why is calendar year categorical?

Comment: This is what I mean by _"splitting the data"_ as explained by `R` help (`survSplit` function of the `survival` pkg): _"Given a survival data set and a set of specified cut times, split each record into multiple subrecords at each cut time. The new data set will be in ‘counting process’ format, with a start time, stop time, and event status for each record."_

Calendar year is categorical because I want to plot a graph of the incidence rate for every calendar year (1998...2009). Something like the panel B of this [picture](http://chestjournal.chestpubs.org/content/138/2/298/F2.medium.gif).

Comment: It might be useful to move your later edit to an answer and accept it as it essentially answers the question.